# Error when trying to build Jekyll 3.4.3 after upgrading

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I just recently did a bunch of upgrading on my jekyll site to get a plugin to install and now when I got to build I get this:

```
`jekyll 3.4.3 | Error:  undefined method `gsub' for 25:Integer`
```

The full stack is:

```
Configuration file: /Users/susanjrobertson/Sites/jekyll_site/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/susanjrobertson/Sites/jekyll_site
       Destination: /Users/susanjrobertson/Sites/jekyll_site/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
/Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:213:in `slugify': undefined method `gsub' for 25:Integer (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/drops/url_drop.rb:22:in `title'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/drops/drop.rb:52:in `public_send'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/drops/drop.rb:52:in `[]'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/url.rb:112:in `block in generate_url_from_drop'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/url.rb:102:in `gsub'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/url.rb:102:in `generate_url_from_drop'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/url.rb:69:in `generate_url'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/url.rb:60:in `generated_url'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/url.rb:40:in `to_s'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/document.rb:200:in `url'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/document.rb:214:in `destination'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/regenerator.rb:176:in `regenerate_document?'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/regenerator.rb:25:in `regenerate?'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:451:in `block (2 levels) in render_docs'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:450:in `each'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:450:in `block in render_docs'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:449:in `each'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:449:in `render_docs'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:190:in `render'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:69:in `process'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/command.rb:26:in `process_site'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:63:in `build'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:34:in `process'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/exe/jekyll:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/jekyll:22:in `load'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/susanjrobertson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I'm not the most adept with these things and have no idea what's going on here or how to fix it. X-Code is up to date, I'm using a ruby package manager to get the gems working together, but still am seeing this final error.

Any ideas? And Thank you!

Comment: I found if I build with an older version of Jekyll (2.4) I can run the server and it's all fine, which is an OK workaround for me for now. But I would like to understand what's up with Jekyll 3.

Answer (score 0):

After installation I just had the same error. Went to the jekyll-docs gem directory and ran...

jekyll serve

That command exited with...

```
Configuration file: C:/ruby217/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-docs-3.1.1/site/_config.yml Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-feed or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-feed' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at http://jekyllrb.com/help/! jekyll 3.1.1 | Error: jekyll-feed
```

So I did...

gem install jekyll-feed
jekyll serve

This time...

```
Configuration file: C:/ruby217/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-docs-3.1.1/site/_config.yml Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-redirect-from or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-redirect-from' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at http://jekyllrb.com/help/! jekyll 3.1.1 | Error: jekyll-redirect-from
```

Again...

gem install jekyll-redirect-from
jekyll serve

This time...

`Configuration file: C:/ruby217/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-docs-3.1.1/site/_config.yml Source: C:/ruby217/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-docs-3.1.1/site Destination: C:/ruby217/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-docs-3.1.1/site/_site Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental Generating... Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have pygments or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- pygments' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at http://jekyllrb.com/help/! Liquid Exception: pygments in C:/ruby217/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-docs-3.1.1/site/_docs/assets.md ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT: ------------------------------------` pygments

So I opened _config.yml (and there at the end of file were those 2 gems listed which I installed above. I should have opened the _config.yml first) and changed this line...

highlighter: pygments

to..

highlighter: rouge

because rouge was already installed on system. After that I ran...

jekyll serve

and voila. It worked.

Conclusion: required dependencies are not resolving correctly.

Comment: Interesting. I don't have any plugins in my config, the pagination plugin would be my first one, but hadn't added yet to the config as I was trying to get the site to build as it was first.

Answer (score 0):

So, a friend in another place answered this question for me!

I had a post that was the following slug: 25 and Jekyll didn't like that at all, I changed it to twenty-five and it was all good!

Hope this helps someone else :)